# composer dependencies injection

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

On my projects, repman is used for external dependencies, but I also have internal dependencies that I want to receive from gitlab, repman repositories are indicated in my composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo-repman.domain.su"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://domain-repo-repman.domain.su"
        },
        {
            "packagist": false
        }
    ],
```

If I add all my dependencies to this section with higher priority and specify the vcs source for them, then the composer will take them from GitLab, but their list is quite large.

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@gitlab.domain.su:to/dependency1.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@gitlab.domain.su:to/dependency2.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@gitlab.domain.su:to/dependency3.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@gitlab.domain.su:to/dependency4.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@gitlab.domain.su:to/dependency5.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@gitlab.domain.su:to/dependency6.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo-repman.domain.su"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://domain-repo-repman.domain.su"
        },
        {
            "packagist": false
        }
    ],
```

These are just some of them, can i somehow put them in a separate file and have it be used as a repository in the composer when using the **composer update** or analogues **composer update to/*** command, similar to indicating them in the repositories section of composer.json?

I tried to put them in a file and specified them in the composer.json config section:

```
"config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "php-http/discovery": false
        },
        "repositories-file": "./repositories.json"
    },
```

but if i removed them from the repositories section, the composer continued to take packages from Repman.

Comment: I do not think in composer, there is any native feature that allows you to specify repositories in a separate file directly. The solution would be by using a script to merge the contents of a separate repositories file into your composer.json before running composer commands.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is to set up a [satis](https://github.com/composer/satis) project (a kind of own packagist) and configure the gitlab repositories there. Then you only have to add the satis endpoint in your composer.json and you can get the dependencies from this repository